# Stop Chrome omnibox from converting search terms to URLs

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar, omnibox

for the most time I am searching the internet via Chrome's omnibox. However, wehen entering single words it converts that search term to an URL and sends me to that webpage. Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start your query with a question mark. As soon as you type it, omnibar will enter 'search mode' and will stop interpreting queries as URLs.

There's also a keyboard shortcut to do this: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: this is very helpful. Is there also a way turn off the above described behavior all together? If not, I will mark your answer as accepted =)

Comment: I'm not aware of such option, but maybe someone else will come up with a solution.